# System.ArgumentNullException: 'String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s'

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

When i submit the registration form i get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'String reference not set to an instance of a String.
>   Parameter name: s'

it's coming form the hashing password class

```
public static class Crypto
{
    public static string Hash(string value)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(
            SHA256.Create()
                .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `value`?

Comment: `SHA256.Create()` hands back an object which implements `IDisposable`. To be a good citizen, you should `Dispose()` of it via a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check `value` for null (or empty) before calling the rest of the methods:

```
public static string Hash(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
    var hash = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes)
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Having each method's result in its own variable will also help you to debug and better understand the flow.

Comment: Hashing an empty string should be valid.